# Ways to implement an own registration process

Tags: rest-api, login, registration

I want to start a project and first I check the technical feasibility. I want to implement a login area. There a lot of people can registrate and have the possiblity to work with an interactive mindmap. The data should be evaluated (inputs, tracking) in Salesforce. After the registration a lead should be created automatically. It’s not required that everybody who want’s to registrate have to posess an own licence. Is it only possible with a third party system (external web portal), which can communicate with Salesforce with the REST API or exists another way to solve the problem with minimal effort?
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use Salesforce Portal licenses or Salesforce Community Licenses or guest profile to perform that logic or you can use full-licensed one dedicated API-Enabled user for all of your communication.